# What does GA means in hibernate versions?

Tags: hibernate, software-lifecycle

What does GA means in hibernate versions?

Comment: The term GA is generic and applies to any software release in general. May be you should re-tag and restructure your question.

Comment: Made an edit, in the hope it will be accepted.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

General Availability. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle).

> General availability (GA) is the point where all necessary
> commercialization activities have been completed and the software has
> been made available to the general market either via the web or
> physical media.